# Answer color in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to make sure that when choosing, the answer is highlighted in red if not correct, and green if correct. How can this be implemented in Flutter?

```
    Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Text("Вопрос ${questionNumber + 1} из ${documentList.length}",
            style: new TextStyle(
                fontSize: 22.0,color: Colors.white
            ),),
          new SizedBox(
            height: 10.0,
          ),
          Image.network(documentList[currentQuestionIndex]["image"]),
          new SizedBox(
            height: 10.0,
          ),
          Text(documentList[currentQuestionIndex]["question"],style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16.0),textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
          new SizedBox(
            height: 20.0,
          ),
        ],

      )];
    List<String> options =
        List<String>.from(documentList[currentQuestionIndex]["options"]);
  for (int i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  widgets.add(
  ListTile(
  title: Text("${(i + 1).toString()}. ${options[i]}.",style: TextStyle(color:Colors.white))
  ,onTap: () {questionNumber++;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

take a variable e.g. `isAnswerCorrect=false;`

on answer selection, set the flag as per the result.

```
setState(() {
    isAnswerCorrect=true ||OR|| false;
  });
```

Now based on the flag you can set the color of a text.

```
Text({ANSWER}, style: TextStyle(color: isAnswerCorrect ? Colors.green : Colors.red))
```

Comment: I tried your example and as a result I get all the answers in red or green
I added a variable and action when pressed                                                                                              I edited the code in question

Comment: you have to manually set the text for the correct answer. Can you add some code that how you are showing the answers?

Comment: I updated the code and show the widget that displays the question image and answer options